# Parameter Error while Activating a Font

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have to activate a Font in Mac OSX 10.5. For that I referred the [ATS](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/ATS/Reference/reference.html). And I coded like this.

```
    NSString *filePath =  @"/Users/userName/Desktop/Fonts/Impasto.otf";
    CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    OSStatus status = ATSFontSetAutoActivationSettingForApplication(kATSFontAutoActivationEnabled,url);
    if(status == paramErr)
    {
        NSLog(@"parameter error");
    }
```

But I am getting `parameter Error` for this code. I can't able to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm merely interpreting the docs, I haven't got actual experience with ATS.*

From the documentation for `ATSFontSetAutoActivationSettingForApplication`:

> Sets the auto-activation setting for the specified application **bundle**.

And then for the second parameter:

> A valid file URL for an **application**. Pass `NULL` to specify the current process.

I read it as: the method activates all the fonts in a given app bundle. You would either pass `(CFURLRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]` or simply `NULL`. To activate a font outside your bundle you might need `ATSFontActivateFromFileReference`.

Comment: thank you.. I used ATSFontActivateFromFileReference and its woking great :)